# textViewDidEndEditing is not called

Tags: iphone, ios, uitextview, uitextviewdelegate

I'm new to iOS development.

I have written header file following like this

```
@interface TextView : UITextView <UITextViewDelegate, UIPopoverControllerDelegate>
```

in **TextView.h.**

The implementation file code is following :

```
- (BOOL)textViewShouldBeginEditing:(TextView *)textView
{
    ZWLog(@"called should begin edit");
    return YES;
}

- (void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(TextView *)textView
{
    ZWLog(@"called did begin edit");
}

- (BOOL)textViewShouldEndEditing:(TextView *)textView
{
    ZWLog(@"called should end editing");
    return YES;
}

- (void)textViewDidEndEditing:(TextView *)textView
{
    ZWLog(@"view did end edit");
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)textView:(TextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
{
    //my own code
    return YES;
}

- (void)textViewDidChange:(TextView *)textView
{
   //my own code
}
```

When i start typing a character in `UITextView`, I got response from

- `textViewShouldBeginEditing`.
- `textViewDidBeginEditing`.
- `shouldChangeTextInRange`.
- `textViewDidChange`.

But I didn't get any response from `textViewDidEndEditing` or `textViewShouldEndEditing`. Do you have any idea why these are not getting called?

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: The method textViewDidEndEditing is getting called when KeyBoard Disappears in other words when user stop typing in the textview and resignfirstresponder is being called.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

textViewDidEndEditing is called when textfield resigns its first responder, when the keyboard disappears.

Answer (score 3):

make sure you've linked your delegate properly from .xib

and use the below methods as it is and take a look it will get called

```
-(BOOL)textViewShouldEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{
    ZWLog(@"textViewShouldEndEditing");
    return TRUE;
}

- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
{
    ZWLog(@"shouldChangeTextInRange");
    // Any new character added is passed in as the "text" parameter
    if ([text isEqualToString:@"\n"])
    {
        [textView resignFirstResponder];
        return FALSE;
    }

    // For any other character return TRUE so that the text gets added to the view
    return TRUE;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> MAke Sure that your delegate is attched in your XIB file with your
>   TextView if it is in XIB file.